# spring-data-jpa : Should I need to configure myself for production?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am totally newbie with spring-boot. I read about **spring-data-jpa** [tutorial](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-one-configuration/). I saw alot of configuration codes for `DataSource`,`EntityManagerFactory`,`JpaTransactionManager` etc; But when I used with spring-boot , these are done by declaring a few properties in `applications.properties` file as ..

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

I didn't insert any persistence context configurations (even @Repository annotation on my repostory interfaces). My test methods run correctly.

But I am curious about the question Can I use as these for production? I saw the log message from test methods

> INFO 8108 --- [       Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

I don't know `persistence unit 'default'` is good enough for production.

Comment: I hope this configuration won't work for your production environment, because that would mean your production database has a user named 'root' and password 'root'. Other than that you're just showing a fear of the unknown here. Rather than follow some random tutorial, read the spring boot documentation.

Comment: @Gimby I saw spring-boot reduces significant amount of configurations. As my question , I don't need to configure `DataSource`,`EntityManagerFactory`,`JpaTransactionManager` etc. But I don't know I should use spring-boot's auto configuration for my project or I should configure them myself for later production wide configurations *(eg : multiple datasources,connection pool,caching)*. I am curious spring-boot's configuration can also do everythings what I need for later or not. That's what I am asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

One common way to configure and manage a `DataSource` in production is through [JNDI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/). From [the Spring Boot Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-a-jndi-datasource):

> **29.1.3 Connection to a JNDI DataSource**
>
> If you are deploying your Spring Boot application to an Application
>   Server you might want to configure and manage your DataSource using
>   your Application Servers built-in features and access it using JNDI.
>
> The `spring.datasource.jndi-name` property can be used as an alternative
>   to the `spring.datasource.url`, `spring.datasource.username` and
>   `spring.datasource.password` properties to access the `DataSource` from a
>   specific JNDI location. For example, the following section in
>   application.properties shows how you can access a JBoss AS defined
>   `DataSource`:
>
> `spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/customers`

You will then have to configure your `DataSource` in your Application Server. For example in JBoss : [DataSource configuration in JBoss AS7.1](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/DataSource+configuration)